# JQuery tabs in IE not showing pictures

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

The problem I am having is that my pictures do not show up in the dynamic JQuery tabs in IE8 and below, but they show up in every other browser. I believe that it is associated with how the tabs load using JQuery because the pictures show up fine when I do not load the code. I used JQuery .hide() and fadeIn() functions in order to change tabs.

Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about: http://www.marinicorp.net/jquerytabs.htm

Here is a link to the web page itself: http://www.marinicorp.net/services.aspx

If you need anymore information just let me know.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("selected").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabNavigation li").click(function () {

    $("ul.tabNavigation li").removeClass("selected"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("selected"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li><a href="#tabCon">Construction Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabLand">Landscaping Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabSnow">Plowing Services</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabCon" class="tab_content">
         <table style="position: absolute; top:35px; left:40px;">
       <tr>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/pipeLay.gif" /></td>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/projMan.gif" /></td>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/surveyeng.gif" /></td>
       </tr>
       </table>  
    </div>
    <div id="tabLand" class="tab_content">
<table style=" position: absolute; left:40px; top:35px;"> <tr>
       <td ><img class="tables" src="Images/playGrounds.gif" /></td>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/plantTrees.gif" /></td>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/genLand.gif" /></td>
       </tr>
       </table>               
    </div>
    <div id="tabSnow" class="tab_content">
      <table style=" position: absolute; left:40px; top:35px;">
       <tr>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/snowplow.gif" /></td>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/shovelers.gif" /></td>
       <td><img class="tables" src="Images/bobcat.gif" /></td>
       </tr>
       </table>     
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab_content {padding: 19px 0 22px 16px}
#tabs{top:380px;left:-10px;position: absolute; z-index:3;}
#tabs .tables{margin: 0px 13px 0px 13px;padding: 0px;border: 2px outset #999999;z-     index:-1;}
UL.tabNavigation{list-style: none; margin: 0;padding: 0;}
UL.tabNavigation LI{display: inline;}
UL.tabNavigation LI A{padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;background-color: #C0C0C0;text decoration: none;font-size: 12pt;color: #000000;font-family: Tahoma;}
UL.tabNavigation LI A.selected, UL.tabNavigation LI A:hover{border width:0px;background-color: #C0C0C0;padding: 10px 20px 13px 20px;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 12pt;}        
UL.tabNavigation LI A:focus {outline: 0;}
div.tabs > div{padding: 5px;margin-top: 11px;width: 620px;height: 330px;}               
div.tabs > div h2 {margin-top: 0;}
#tabCon{background-color: #C0C0C0;}
#tabLand{background-color: #C0C0C0;}
#tabSnow{background-color: #C0C0C0;}
.waste {min-height: 1000px;}
```

Comment: Can you post a working example, or the code?

Answer (score 1):

had an interesting one just like this today - turned out it was the encoding of the image files themselves!!! try re-saving the images with fireworks or photyshop or gimp or what ever and see what happens.

(was so tempted to just say don't use ie8 then ;) )

Comment: haha! trust me I hate all IE versions up until 9 (which so far I like a lot...finally they caught up with w3c standards). Thanks for the tip though, I will try it out.

Comment: Too bad IE9 completely excludes anyone who's not using Vista or Windows 7 (which is all your high-dollar corporate users)  Way to go, Microsoft....

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this.  Use [JQuery UI's tabs.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)  It natively handles slow-load scenarios, browser discrepancies, and FOUC issues that are common with tabbed menu solutions.

You can then simply style the tabs using CSS.  It should be faster and less intrusive, with significantly less work to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will make sure to learn up on this method and use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... IE does not load the images within the tab with the div simultaneously, so instead of using the fadein() function with the id of each div, I created a class for each div.tab and image within the tabs that are all faded in when JQuery calls that class.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
  <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a href="#tabLand" name=".tabLand">Landscaping Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabCon" name=".tabCon">Construction Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabSnow" name=".tabSnow">Plowing Services</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabLand" class="tabLand">
    <table style="position: absolute; left:40px; top:35px;"> 
       <tr>
       <td><img class="tabLand" src="Images/playGrounds.jpg" /></td>
       <td><img class="tabLand" src="Images/plantTrees.jpg" /></td>
       <td><img class="tabLand" src="Images/genLand.jpg" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
     </table>               
    </div>
    <div id="tabCon" class="tabCon">
    <table style=" position: absolute; left:40px; top:35px;"> <tr>
       <td ><img class="tabCon" src="Images/pipeLay.jpg" /></td>
       <td><img class="tabCon" src="Images/projMan.jpg" /></td>
       <td><img class="tabCon" src="Images/surveyeng.jpg" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
       </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabSnow" class="tabSnow">
      <table style=" position: absolute; left:40px; top:35px;">
       <tr>
       <td><img class="tabSnow" src="Images/snowplow.jpg" /></td>
       <td><img class="tabSnow" src="Images/shovelers.jpg" /></td>
       <td><img class="tabSnow" src="Images/bobcat.jpg" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
       </table>     
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabArray = new Array();
    tabArray[0] = ".tabCon";
    tabArray[1] = ".tabLand";
    tabArray[2] = ".tabSnow";
    var p = tabArray.length;
    //When page loads...
    for (x = 0; x < p; x++) {
        $(tabArray[x]).hide();
    }

    $("ul.tabNavigation li:first").addClass("selected").show(); //Activate first tab
    var firstTab = $("ul.tabNavigation li:first").find("a").attr("name"); //Show first tab content
    $(firstTab).show();
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabNavigation li").click(function () {
        var clearTab = $("ul.tabNavigation li.selected").find("a").attr("name");
        $("ul.tabNavigation li").removeClass("selected"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(clearTab).hide(); //Hide all tab content
        $(this).addClass("selected"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("name"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```